# Find 10-th, n-th derivative of $ \dfrac{e^x}{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Let $y=\dfrac{e^x}{x}$, find $y^{(10)}, y^{(n)} ? $.

I tried to multiply both side with $x$ and some other ways then apply Leibniz formula but seem like it does'nt work.

$y = \dfrac{e^x}{x} \Rightarrow xy=e^x,\;then\; (xy)^{(10)} = e^x \Rightarrow e^x = \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{10} \begin{pmatrix} 10 \\ k \end{pmatrix}x^{(k)}y^{(10-k)} $

$ = xy^{(10)} +10y^{(9)}$...

Much appreciated any helps, hints from you guys!

Comment: Why didn't you just start taking derivatives?

Comment: Calculate $y'$, $y''$, $y'''$, etc. until you see what emerges as a clear pattern, make a conjecture, then prove it by induction. The first step is easily done with the assistance of a website like Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: Why stop at $10y^{(9)}$? If you keep going it'll be clear that the recurrence formed by your approach involves only a few previous derivatives at a time, which is somewhat easily solved.

Comment: opps! my bad, thanks!

Comment: Sometimes it's tempting to search for "tricks" immediately, when doing it the naive way can give you patterns. Kinda luck based haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just apply Leibniz directly?

$$y^{(10)}=\sum_{k=0}^{10}\binom{10}k(x^{-1})^{(k)}(e^x)^{(10-k)}=\sum_{k=0}^{10}\binom{10}k\frac{(-1)^kk!}{x^{k+1}}e^x$$

Comment: Yeah thanks you guys so much with your help! i just started learning calculus so you know.... My bad anyway!

Answer (score 1):

We can apply the Leibniz formula to the product of $e^x $ and $ x^{-1}$ since any order of derivative of $e^x$ remains the same,i.e. $e^x$. By inspection, you can find the kth order of derivative of $x^{-1}$ is $(-1)^k \frac{k!}{x^k}$. Hence the result is $e^x\sum_{k = 0}^{n} {n\choose k}(-1)^k \frac{k!}{x^k}$

Comment: A bit late there, and the application of Leibniz's rule is done incorrectly.

Comment: so sorry for the type error. I correct it.

Answer (score 0):

$$y'=\frac{e^xx-e^x}{x^2}=\frac{e^x(x-1)}{x^2}$$

$$y''=\frac{e^xx^2+e^xx^2(x-1)-e^x2x(x-1)}{x^4}=\frac{e^x(x^2-2x+2)}{x^3}$$

$$y'''=\frac{e^x(x^3-3x^2+6x-6)}{x^4}$$

$$y''''=\frac{e^x(x^4-4x^3+12x^2-24+24)}{x^4}$$

now conjecture and prove using induction

:)

(Coefficients are permutation numbers, alternating signs)